# Multiple Instances of SharePoint App

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin

I have a question that can we create multiple of a SharePoint app no matter if it is either SharePoint hosted or Provider hosted or AutoHosted. I want to know that same as a webpart, can I create multiple instance of an app part on a single site or on a single webpage in my site? If yes then how? and if No then why?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Multiple instances of the same App in SharePoint is not possible in same site.
2. You can add multiple instances of an app part on a single page and in order to do that you have to follow the steps as you follow for adding a web part in a page.

Comment: can i configure the app part instances with different settings same as we do in webpart ?

Comment: Yes, for that you have to create app part property as we do in web parts.

Comment: ok, can you provide me some link which can guide me through the app property ?

is there any concept like " EditoPart " or " ToolPart " in Apps ?

Comment: http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Client-Web-Part-Custom-Properties-and-Query-String-Standard-Token-in-SharePoint-2013-Napa-App.aspx

above link is the example for adding properties in SharePoint apps.