# Sharepoint-hosted app-instance of an app in the same site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, survey, survey-list

I have created a sharepoint-hosted survey app and deployed to my site.I am able to create a single survey with this app.But when i need to create another survey in the same site,Im not able to add the app again to the site.I need the app to behave like SP survey list.How can create multiple instance of the app in the same site.
What logic is used in SP survey list?Can anyone provide a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Installing multiple instance of App on single site is not possible. You can do it in different sites.

But still if you want to achieve this then you can try with different settings as we use in WebParts.

Please have a look to [this](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Client-Web-Part-Custom-Properties-and-Query-String-Standard-Token-in-SharePoint-2013-Napa-App.aspx)

[source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/153037/30145)